# Using linebreaks openly in PHP code valid?

Tags: php, html, standards

I have the following code where I am using HTML 4.01 Strict:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>

<?php echo "Hello World!"; ?> <br>
<?php echo "Hello World!"; ?> <br>

</body>
</html>
```

However, the use of `<br>` tags in `<body>` tags isn't allowed by the HTML 4.01 standard. So, must I enclose my PHP code in the paragraph tags?

Comment: It has nothing to do with PHP. This is HTML standards.

Comment: I haven't seen the PHP code written in `<p>` in many of the books so I'm wondering if I should add the required tags where needed. It also said to use `<br />` tag with space and a forward slash as a rule.

Comment: No, because PHP is run on the server-side and produces the HTML content. It's the result of the PHP code that ends up in the `<p>` tags.

Comment: It's 2013, start using html5 :)

Comment: It appears to me as if very rare people would actually use "HTML strict" judging from the books I have seen on HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Valid" is a very broad term.

- *Syntactically correct* -- yes, the code will run without error
- *Semantically correct PHP* -- PHP does not really have a concept of semantics other than best practices.  Some argue for and others against combining PHP code with HTML at all, so some would consider what you are doing to be wrong for separate reasons.
- *Semantically correct HTML* -- You should consider the HTML that is rendered by PHP as the HTML that is required to be semantically correct.  *That* should be validated and not the input PHP code/HTML combination.  I'm not that familiar with the 4.01 standard, so if you need to follow it and it says not to use `<br>` in `<body>` (sounds like a bizarre rule to me, though) then just make sure that the *output* code uses `<p>` tags correctly.  Seems like this would require surrounding the php blocks with `<p></p>` in this specific case.

Answer (score 0):

> However, the use of `<br>` tags in  tags isn't allowed by the HTML 4.01 standard.

In the DTD for HTML 4.01 Strict (http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/strict.dtd), the BR element is classified as 'special', and thus 'inline'. But the content model of the BODY element does not allow 'inline' content, only 'block' elements (plus a few others: SCRIPT, INS, DEL).

So, with respect to the HTML generated by your example PHP code, it's not just the `<br>` tags that are invalid, it's also the `Hello World!` -- that's inline content too.

> So, must I enclose my PHP code in the paragraph tags?

Well, it wouldn't *have* to be `<P>` tags, any 'block-level' element would do, as far as DTD-validity is concerned. But P would probably be best. (Or you could consider PRE.)